# Retrieving Python errors into an Oracle database

Tags: python, linux, database, oracle

My use case is the following: i developed a small python script which does some time-series analysis and then writes the output into a database table where it's used by an Oracle application. The script resides on the server and is run from the Oracle interface. All is working good but i want to be able to retrieve any potential errors from the script into a database table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either:

- wrap all of the script's main logic in a `try: except Exception as exc:` block, and then use the exception handler to post the traceback (`traceback.format_traceback()`) to your database
- use a separate wrapper script that runs your script, and in case it fails (returncode != 0), post the stderr output to your database